# For a linear transformation how can a set be characterized?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation from V to W. Consider the set of vectors S in V s.t.
Tx = w where w is a non-zero vector in W. Characterize the set S.

Comment: What do you mean by "characterise"?

Comment: Characterise : What can you tell about S. Its properties/characteristics.

Comment: That is a very vague question. You can characterise it as $S=\{x\in S: Tx\neq 0\in W\}$. Every possible property of $S$ is thus described, since you know exactly what $S$ is.

Comment: Probably $w$ is a given vector of $W$, though the formulation makes this unclear.